# Move the recent activity css to a separate file

Tags: feature-request, design

While debugging my newest, daftest, [GreaseMonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23656) I noticed that the css for the "[Recent Activity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/130494)" pages is inlined in the html. A moderate performance improvement could be achieved by moving the css to a separate file and serving it from sstatic.net

I just checked the character count, and the css accounts for 1,217 characters (1,948 with spaces). My recent activity page for today has 11,467 (16,011 with spaces), and on quieter days can have as few as 8,923 (13,351 with spaces). So this could save around 7-15% of the page depending on gzip and minification usage.

Does this count as a bug, a feature, or a feature request, or just my OCD flaring up again? I'll just spam it with tags and let the fates decide.

Answer (score 1):

since that page is only visible to you, that specific user (and 2-10 moderators at most), it's not very high on our list of things to optimize.

Comment: but (I assume) the css is common to all activity pages. So it would apply for anyone viewing their own profile page?

Comment: @Rich Seller: I agree with you, but its probably outside of the critic path/critic load of the page.